# How to always validate an angular json schema form?

Tags: angular-schema-form

I am using [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form), and ran into a problem that when I load a schema and a form from a server using REST, the validation sometimes did not kick in. I could post a schema even though some fields were required.

How can I always be sure that the required fields in the form has to be filled in by the user before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using `$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');` before submitting the form works ([from the docs](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#handling-submit)).

```
$scope.onSubmit = function(form) {
    // First we broadcast an event so all fields validate themselves
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');

    // Then we check if the form is valid
    if (form.$valid) {
      // ... do whatever you need to do with your data.
    }
  }
```

However, we can not disable any buttons beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

@John you can set a value in your model that is part of a display condition. That allows you to hide the buttons on submit and then re-enable them when you are ready for the user to submit the form again for any reason.